# Update not working on newly added column in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I created new column in MySQL db i.e. otp and trying to update this by using below Mutation but it's not working, however same function updating all other columns like name of user but not updating otp column. I added otp column in user's Schema & model as well. Can anyone help me in finding what exactly I am missing in this. One more point when retrieving data from user's table otp field always null.

```
sendotp: async (_, {email }) => {

  return User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: email,
    },
    limit: 1,
  }).then(async (user) => {
    if (user) {

      otp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      let updatedUser = await User.update(
        { otp: otp, name:otp },
        { where: { id: user.id }, returning: true }
      );
     
        return user;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new AuthenticationError("An account does not exist with this email.");          
    }
  });
}
```

> Here is schema
> extend type Mutation {
> sendotp(email: String!): User
> }

```
type User {
id: ID!
uuid: String
name: String
email: String
otp: String
}
```

> Model of above resolver as

```
"use strict";
 module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 var User = sequelize.define(
"User",
{
  uuid: DataTypes.STRING,
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.STRING,
  otp: DataTypes.STRING,
 } ....
```

> Resolver not returning otp filed in simple select query as well. Select query result as

```
{\"id\":435,\"uuid\":\"dfds\",\"name\":\"602a\",\"email\":\"test2@yopmail.com\",}
```

Comment: First of all, it seems that you are returning the user you fetched instead of the user you updated.

Comment: That is intentional, database already have value in that field. I tried by changing data type string with other like Int etc. It's very strange next and previous field both got updated with same function but not this one. I added otp filed in DB now and updated Schema and Model accordingly as this is just string not a big deal. Is there any cache cleaning DB migration or any extra thing required to reflect changes OR any why to debug this issue ? Like by printing query etc.?